# C#: Nested dictionary issue

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have the code below which is intended to build a dictionary object with the following construction `Dictionary<string<Dictionary<string, string>`. For some reason each time I add an item to it the key text is correct but the value (dictionary) overwrites the previous one. This is probably better explained like this:

**Iteration 1**

- key1, dictionary1

**Iteration 2**

- key1, dictionary2
- key2, dictionary2

**Iteration 3**

- key1, dictionary3
- key2, dictionary3
- key3, dictionary3

What is causing this and how can I fix this code to stop it overwriting the dictionary in each entry?

```
QueryNameUserQueryString = new Dictionary<string, string>();
DialectDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();

while (dataBaseConnection.NextRecord())
                {
                if (QueryNameUserQueryString != null)
                    {
                    QueryNameUserQueryString.Clear();
                    }

                string dialect = dataBaseConnection.GetFieldById (0);

                //If no dialect then carry out next iteration
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty (dialect))
                    {
                    continue;
                    }

                try
                    {
                    dataBaseConnection2.ExecutePureSqlQuery ("SELECT * FROM " + sqlFactoryTable + " WHERE SQL_FACTORY_DIALECT = '" + dialect + "'");
                    }
                catch
                    {
                    dataBaseConnection.Close();
                    dataBaseConnection2.Close();

                    throw;
                    }

                //Do we have query strings for this dialect?
                if (!dataBaseConnection2.HasRows())
                    {
                    continue;
                    }

                //loop through query strings
                while (dataBaseConnection2.NextRecord())
                    {
                    string queryName = dataBaseConnection2.GetFieldById (2);
                    string queryString = dataBaseConnection2.GetFieldById (3);
                    string user = dataBaseConnection2.GetFieldById (4);

                    //create composite key for dictionary
                    string compositeKey = dialect + "," + queryName + "," + user;

                    if (QueryNameUserQueryString != null)
                        {
                        //Construct our query string dictionary
                        QueryNameUserQueryString.Add (compositeKey, queryString);
                        }
                    }

                //If we have a query string dictionary
                if (QueryNameUserQueryString != null)
                    {
                    //Ensure m_dialect dictionary is not null
                    if (DialectDictionary != null)
                        {
                        //Construct our dictionary entry for this dialect
                        DialectDictionary.Add (dialect, QueryNameUserQueryString);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: You seem to be using the same instance of `QueryNameUserQueryString` on every iteration.

Comment: You are adding QueryNameUserQueryString multiple times - which means the DialectDictionary is going to have multiple references to the same object. If you update it, the changes will be reflected in all items in the DialectDictionary

Comment: But as this is added to another dictionary object shouldnt it add a copy of the dictionary at that time into it as the value? Am I misunderstanding how the dictionary object works?

Comment: No. You add a reference to your QNUQS dictionary. Not a deep copy. =)

Comment: No - it's passed by reference

Comment: Ah I see. What would you suggest is the best way to fix this?

Comment: JleruOHeP's answer as a beginning. =) But, really - put the variable inside the while-scope instead. That way you're limiting the scope of it so it can only exist once per iteration, not over all iterations.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking that the dictionary was stored as a new object when added to the parent dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be using the same instance of `QueryNameUserQueryString` on every iteration. When it's added to the `DialectDictionary`, it's added as a reference - not a copy of the original.

To "properly" solve the issue, I would move the declaration of your `QueryNameUserQueryString` variable inside the while-scope. That way you would make sure that it can only exist in the scope of a single iteration, not across several. When it's added to the `DialectDictionary`, the reference lives on in that dictionary and you're safe to leave the scope.

Comment: Accepted for being a more intuitive solution and explaining the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You are using same instance of QueryNameUserQueryString everytime. Replace

```
QueryNameUserQueryString.Clear();
```

with

```
QueryNameUserQueryString = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```